# Select two rows from bit array based on int array python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I have two arrays one Int, and one is bit

```
s = [ [1]          x = [ [1 0 0 0 0]
      [4]              [1 1 1 1 0]
      [9]              [0 1 1 1 0]
      [0]              [0 0 1 0 0]
      [3] ]            [0 1 1 0 0]]
```

I want to find the smallest two elements in s (random given) then (select and print) two rows from x (random given) based on s array,
for example, the smallest elements in s[i] are s[3]=0, s[0]=1, so i want to select x[3][0 0 1 0 0], and x[0][1 0 0 0 0]

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
s= np.random.randint(5, size=(5))
x= np.random.randint (2, size=(5, 5))
print (s)
print (x)
```

I tried my best using the "for loop" but no luck, any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your effort on your for-loop so that we can help you fix or correct it.

Comment: I love too, but it is not very clear otherwise I will share it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.argpartition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) to find out the index of the two smallest elements from `s` and use it as row index to subset `x`:

```
s
# array([3, 0, 0, 1, 2])

x
# array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

x[s.argpartition(2)[:2], :]
# array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was very helpful